# Motherboard intermittently won't load peripherals

Tags: motherboard, bios

I am having some trouble with my home Desktop and I am trying to figure out whether or not the problem is likely to be BIOS / hardware or software. Any and all help would be much appreciated!

**System:**

I have a Gigabyte Z87X D3H motherboard with BIOS version F5.  I dual boot Windows and linux off of separate SSDs where the Windows drive is the first SATA slot and the linux one is in the 3rd (I had to unplug the primary drive when installing linux as to avoid grub / sda issues so that has not been a problem).

**Problems:**

1. As of today (after 3 years of use with no problems), my linux
   system drops mouse / keyboard support. This either prevents me from
   logging in at all, or occurs within about 2 minutes of use. I have
   looked into software solutions for my Linux Mint 17 install, but
   given the nature of the problem and some other symptoms, I believe
   it might be a hardware or BIOS issue.
2. When I boot, the Gigabyte
   loading splash screen shows up for 4 seconds, goes black and hangs
   for about 12 seconds, reappears and then is fully functioning. (This
   isn't really a big deal, but it might help in figuring out what is
   wrong so I am including it).
3. Occasionally, when I boot Windows my
   mouse and keyboard do not work. This is very infrequent, maybe 1 in
   20 boots.
4. My USB 3.0 ports sometimes do not successfully connect to my USB 3.0 external hard drive (not mounting under windows / linux, not providing power to external). Also occasionally does not work with USB 2.0 devices.

I know flashing a BIOS is risky and I'd rather avoid doing so if possible.  Gigabyte seems to be *very* sparing with their change log / documentation so I have been unable to discern whether or not any updates that have come out would be of use (the latest version is 4 iterations later than mine).  Might anyone know what versions F5-F9 have accomplished (in detail)?

Thank you!

Comment: How do your keyboard and mouse connect to the PC (e.g. PS/2 or USB)?  Have you tried a different kb or mouse?  BTW the motherboard does not *"load"* peripherals.  Updating/replacing the BIOS is not likely to solve much; only the splash screen is remotely related.

Comment: This could be PSU trouble, intermittently not providing the output - or not enough of it.

Comment: The keyboard is a dual-USB Corsair K95.  I have an AZZA Dynamo 850W power supply. When I spec'd my rig I do recall leaving plenty of extra wattage for any upgrades / incidentals although I do not presently recall my average or boot power draw.  Perhaps supporting the PSU argument, upon realizing I had an extra external hard drive plugged into my USB 3.0 port, I unplugged it and suddenly was able to have a functioning mouse / keyboard upon next boot in linux.  That would not rule out a faulty port or poor support for a functioning one, however.

Comment: Upon further testing, the problem persists using an external hard drive even in the USB 2.0 ports.  Interestingly enough, I had the keyboard light back up and the mouse come back to life during one of my tests which would suggest to me that spinning up the external disk was just barely too much of a power draw. Hannu, would you mind posting your comment as an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks!